# Sub menus are not showing when importing jquery library

Tags: jquery, ajax, styles, libraries, submenu

When I import jquery library to my web page, my web page is working perfectly. But it was not showing sub menus.
Code I used for importing jquery library :
`<script type="text/javascript" src="result/jquery.min.js"></script>` 
(`jquert.min.js` is in result folder).
[image: Submenus are not showing]

But when I comment the java-script to import jquery library, all the sub menus are showing and some default style of CMS Pro also present. But jquerys in the webpage is not working. My website is based on CMS Pro.
[image: Submenus are showing]

Comment: Only use `code` markdown for... well, code.

Comment: possibly a conflict with another library that uses `$` alias. What other scripts are loading in page?

Comment: Only two possible cases, whether its a relative path mistake or the one @charlietfl mentioned.

Comment: @dShringi I tried whith this(<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">)

Comment: @charlietfl if conflict is there, how can I solve it..

Comment: @VishalVijay Then its possibly a conflict with some other `js`. Just try to use an alias as mentioned above.

Comment: Why are you loading `two jQuery libs` upper one is `1.8.3` and bottom one is `1.4.2`

Comment: @Jai you are righ. But my jQuery is not working with 1.8.3. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is when you load jQuery.js twice, any plugins registered to first version will get wiped out.

Remove second version and all should be fine

Comment: Ya @charlietfl you are right that is the problem. But I don't know why my jquery is not working with 1.8.3. It is working perfectly with jquery 1.4.2 ... Can you see that code please.

Comment: are you loading jQuery before all plugins and dependent code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your console yet?

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} has no method 'jStyling' *(master.js, line 4)*

I see 2 immediate problems:

1. You link to jQuery Twice, and even to two different versions of it:

   - classresults.php

     1. line 20: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.vtulife.com/assets/jquery.js"></script>`
     2. line 146: `<script type="text/javascript" src="result/jquery.min.js"></script>`
2. The "jStyling" plugin is either loaded/linked before jQuery is, or it isn't linked at all.